# synchronized keyword is not locking a linked list and other threads are still polling out objects from it

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, java.util.concurrent

Q1) I created a linked list based implementation of DB Connection Pool. Threads which needs connection poll() it from list and threads release connections using add() or addFirst(). During testing I noticed that even though one thread has locked the list using synchronized(ll) {some code here} , other threads were able to poll() out the connections from the list. This test makes me conclude that only the block of code within {} will be guaranteed to be executed by 1 thread at a time but the object itself i.e. ll , will not get locked and other threads can still write on it. Is that correct ?? then what's the use of putting ll as the monitor ?? I could as well use synchronized(this)..

Q2) If I create the Linked list as thread safe using Collections.synchronizedList() during creation of the List, then can I get rid of the synchronized blocks. Assume I have 2 seperate methods for obtaining connection and releasing connection. Currently both methods uses synchronized blocks to obtain/release connections.

Q3) If I decide to use a non blocking list such as ConcurrentLinkedQueue (we have JDK 1.5) will that help in our case. Our peak connection usage is 30 but we have not imposed any limits in our code, so connections can grow infinitely. We were planning to write a Timer Task which will run in the night and close some connections from the head of the list(old connections), but for executing business logic we would prefer to use connections from tail of the queue since those are latest released connections so that chances of having a non-stale connections are high. But since its a fifo queue so I cannot poll() data from tail of queue, so I am forced to use maybe-stale connections from head of queue. So basically what I need is stack like feature for executing business logic , but queue like feature for implementing timer task. Any data structure which you can suggest.

Comment: JDK 1.5? In 2016? Also: 1. why not a `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead? 2. please show some code

Comment: Only one question per question please.

Comment: Cannot use a blocking queue since we cannot wait for a connection, If I don't get a connection then instead of waiting for it we prefer to create a new connection. bcoz we need to reply back to ATM machine within 10 second SLA. so we have no bound on the number of active connections, thats why we plan to run some timer task in the midnight to remove some connections from the List/Queue since unused connections may go stale overnight due to TCP/Network reset.

Comment: Thread-1 which enters the sync block and sleep 10 sec with monitor on Linked list
<code>
    public void run() {
 
 synchronized(ll) {
   while(true) {
    
    System.out.println(" Sleeping 10 sec ");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
   }
 }
}
</code>


Thread-2 which pops out objects from Linked list even while Thread-1 has locked on it using the synchronized(ll) keyword

    public void run() {
 
 while(true) {
  
  System.out.println("Size of Linked List = " +  ll.size());
   System.out.println(" Sleeping half sec ");
   sleep(500);
   ll.poll();
 }
}

Comment: Next time somebody asks you to add code, please edit your question and add _formatted_ code.  Please do not put the code in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you have some list:

```
LinkedList ll = ...;
```

Synchronizing on `ll` does *not* prevent other threads from accessing the list or modifying the list:

```
synchronized(ll) {
    ...protected code...
    // This does NOT prevent other threads from examining or updating
    // ll while the protected code runs.
}
```

The only thing that a `synchronized` block prevents is, it prevents other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time.

The reason for synchronizing some data structure like a linked list is to prevent other threads from seeing the structure in an invalid state when one thread must create that temporary invalid state in order to do its work.

In order to make it work, the block of code that creates the temporary bad state must be synchronized, and every block of code that must be prevented from seeing the bad state must also be synchronized on the same object.

---

This is useless because no other thread will *ever* be allowed to synchronize on `ll`:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized(ll) {
        while(true) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You generally want to keep `synchronized` blocks as short as possible:  You want the code to get in and get out quickly to minimize the amount of time that other threads will spend waiting for their turn.

Comment: Thanks @James, that answers my first question, could you pls have a look at remaining two which are also related to the same use case, I need  a deque like feature but project is live on Java5 and don't have bandwith to migrate to Java7 which gives this data structure.

Comment: @amit, Re `Collections.synchronizedList()`.  It's like I said above:  The reason for synchronizing _anything_ is to prevent other threads from seeing data in a temporary invalid state.  `Collections.synchronizedList()` gives you a fully synchronized proxy for the `List` object of your choice.  If the only thing that matters is protecting the list from coruption, then that should be sufficient.  But, if your program depends on some relationship between what's in the list and any other data structure, then you may need a lock that covers both structures.

Comment: Re Deques,  A quick google search should turn up plenty of examples of how to implement a deque.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization doesn't lock objects. It locks pieces of code that are synchronizing on the same object. If other pieces of code are using the same object without synchronizing on it, they will proceed.

Comment: IMO, saying that "[synchronization] locks pieces of code" is not helpful advice to noobs.  Reason being, _code_ is not what needs to be protected.  What needs to be protected is _data_.  Noobs need to understand that it is _the coder's responsibility_ to insure that some lock object is associated with any data structure that needs protection, _and_ to insure that _every_ block of code that depends on the data structure is synchronized on that same lock object.